# Is Stack Overflow using the Vue.js JavaScript framework?

Tags: discussion

I'm beginner **Vue.js** learner. Today when working on Stack Overflow, I found that Stack Overflow is using Vue.js.

In fact I'm using the **WappAlyzer** Chrome extension, and it shows that.  This is an screenshot and the proof of this claim:

[image]

But really Stack Overflow is using Vue.js frameworks. In this case Vue.js could attract one of the best and most famous websites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, we are not using vue.js - I don't know where these people get their data from.

Comment: Are you 80% sure? (In contrary to the 20% of that tool :P)

Comment: @Tom - 100% sure. We do have a "vue.js" file in the codebase, but that's a component of codemirror, which is used for the snippets feature (i.e. provides functions and data to *deal* with vue.js, but doesn't use it itself).

Comment: so which javascript framework are you using for stack overflow?

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal - View Source. Developer tools - Sources. They both give you all the details.

Comment: How they get the data: https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/ccdb6949f7210db64cbd4053c0cf1fb3e8befec5/src/apps.json#L10255

Comment: I read the same thing here, https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/js-vuejs/all/all